# What is the difference between mean(x) and calc(x, fun=mean) for RasterStack?

Tags: r, stack, mean, raster

I have around 80 raster stacks with 24 layers each. I'm trying to calculate the mean of all layers for each stack (e.g. mean pixel-wise in 24 layers).

I found two approaches to accomplish this but I get slightly different results in the min-max values. Here is an example:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(9999)

##create example raster list
rasterls=list()
for (i in 1:24){
  r <- raster(nrow=(255*5), ncol=(487*5), vals=runif(255*5*487*5))
  rasterls[[i]] <- r
}
##create raster stack
stackRas <- stack(rasterls)

##calculate mean using mean()
mean(stackRas, na.omit=T)

'''class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1275, 2435, 3104625  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.1478439, 0.1411765  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0.2453108, 0.8256463  (min, max)
'''

##calculate mean using calc(fun=mean)
calc(stackRas, fun = mean, na.omit=T)

'''
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1275, 2435, 3104625  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.1478439, 0.1411765  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : C:/Users/--/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpoVVABX/raster/r_tmp_2021-04-28_120400_4844_87419.grd 
names      : layer
values     : 0.2138654, 0.8183816  (min, max)
'''
```

What is the difference between both approaches? Why the different min-max? Am I missing something? Which one should I use? I'd appreciate any insight. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `na.omit` argument for `mean`.  The correct argument should be `na.rm`.  When you passed a value for na.omit, it was ignored and the two methods differ in their default handling of missing values. If we use the correct argument, the results are the same.

```
mean(stackRas, na.rm=T)
# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 1275, 2435, 3104625  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 0.1478439, 0.1411765  (x, y)
# extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source     : memory
# names      : layer 
# values     : 0.2113316, 0.7704163  (min, max)

calc(stackRas, mean, na.rm=T)
# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 1275, 2435, 3104625  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 0.1478439, 0.1411765  (x, y)
# extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source     : /tmp/RtmpRMo1uo/raster/r_tmp_2021-04-28_124738_12579_61131.grd 
# names      : layer 
# values     : 0.2113316, 0.7704163  (min, max)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification. I changed the argument as indicated and now I get identical results.